# How to write a Url for HttpGet Api in Asp.net mvc when data is getting from textfield of login page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

In my project, I am using three ties Architecture that are 
(UI--> Controller--> DAL). At first I have created HttpPost Api that worked fine on both through UI and through postman. but when I have created Login HttpGet Api for checking User is available on database, my Api is working fine on postman where I an just checked the response of Api (Flow from Controller to DAl), but when I want to use HttpGet Api through web Login page it does not working (Flow from UI to Controller). May be I am doing mistake in Url where I have to Login page text field Id.. Please slove my query..

Here my Code:

Controller:

```
 [HttpGet] 
    public string login(string UserName, string Password)
    {
        Users objUser = new Users();
        bool bResult = objUser.ValidateUser(UserName, Password);
        string strResponse = "";
        if (bResult)
        {
            strResponse = "Login Successful";
        }
        else
        {
            strResponse = "Failed to Login.";
        }

        return strResponse;  
    }
```

DAL:

```
 public bool ValidateUser(string strUserName , string strPassword)
    {
        string strQuery = "SELECT * FROM [dbo].[user] WHERE user_name = '" + strUserName + "' and password_ = '"+ strPassword + "'";

        DataTable dtb = GetDataFromQuery(strQuery);
        if (dtb != null && dtb.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
```

Ajax:

```
function httpMVCGetRequest(url, callback, errcallback) {

url = window.location.origin + url;
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    async: true,
    success: callback,
    error: errcallback
});
```

}

Ajax Function Calling, here I am given ka Url for getting data from my login text field when ever anybody enter data for login.

```
function callSignIn() {

httpMVCGetRequest('/users/login?UserName=$("#nameuser").val()&Password=$("#passsignin").val()', callbackSignIn);  

}
function callbackSignIn(data) {    
alert(data);}
```

HTML (Login Page):

```
<div class="login-form">
            <div class="sign-in-htm">
                <div class="group">
                    <label for="user" class="label">Username</label>
                    <input id="nameuser" type="text" class="input">
                </div>
                <div class="group">
                    <label for="pass" class="label">Password</label>
                    <input id="passsignin" type="password" class="input" data-type="password">
                </div>
                <div class="group">
                    <input id="check" type="checkbox" class="check" checked>
                    <label for="check"><span class="icon"></span> Keep me Signed in</label>
                </div>
                <div class="group">

                    <li class="button"><a onclick="callSignIn();"><center>Sign In</center></a></li>
                </div>
                <div class="hr"></div>
                <div class="foot-lnk">
                    <label for="tab-3">Forgot Password?</label>
                </div>
            </div>
```

when I write this Url on postman it give me respone of successful login

```
http://localhost:3672/api/users/login?UserName=abc&Password=e123
```

but when write this Url on ajax function to get user's input data its stuck..

```
'/users/login?UserName=$("#nameuser").val()&Password=$("#passsignin").val()'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your code like this:

```
 function httpMVCGetRequest(url,    callback, rrcallback) {
    $.get(url, {
        "UserName": $("#nameuser").val(),
        "Password": $("#passsignin").val()
    },
        callback);
}
httpMVCGetRequest('/users/login', callbackSignIn);
```

'/users/login?UserName=$("#nameuser").val()&Password=$("#passsignin").val()' will not work as $("#nameuser") is jquery syntax and writing it as string literal will not evaluate but render it as it is.